# powershell set viso container to autofit content

Tags: powershell

Can anyone help me to set container in viso automatically fits within the content.

To make it easier to understand, see the following picture

From
[image: From]

Become
[image: Become]

I have tried to use marco to record this action to see the command

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.SetContainerFormat visContainerFormatFitToContents
```

but I don't know how to run it via powershell

I tried

```
$pages.selection.SetContainerFormat =2
```

but got error

```
The property 'SetContainerFormat' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:19 char:1
+ $pages.selection.SetContainerFormat =2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is work

```
$viso.ActiveWindow.Selection.SetContainerFormat(2)
```